# Scapy IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, scapy

some of you may say that this question is already answered but it is not , scapy was working very well but suddenly i had to format my computer after that i installed everything correctly , and i get this error every time i need to print ANY information in scapy classes like IP or TCP , etc :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/work/PycharmProjects/Scapy/lesson3.py", line 20, in <module>
print(send(IP(dst='192.168.100.1', ttl=(1, 4))/ICMP(),   return_packets=True).summary()) # if return_packets are True then it will   show a PacketList .
File "C:\Users\work\PycharmProjects\Scapy\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 300, in send
socket = conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs)
File "C:\Users\work\PycharmProjects\Scapy\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 259, in __init__
self.ins = open_pcap(iface, 1600, self.promisc, 100, monitor=monitor)
File "C:\Users\work\PycharmProjects\Scapy\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 914, in open_pcap
if conf.use_npcap and isinstance(iface, NetworkInterface) and iface.ismonitor():
File "C:\Users\work\PycharmProjects\Scapy\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 596, in ismonitor
return self.mode() == "monitor"
File "C:\Users\work\PycharmProjects\Scapy\venv\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 590, in mode
return POWERSHELL_PROCESS.query([_WlanHelper, self.guid[1:-1], "mode"], crp=False, rst_t=True)[0].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and this is the code of the program :

```
send(IP(dst='192.168.100.1', ttl=(1, 4))/ICMP(), return_packets=True).summary()
```

so every time i want to print any information i get that error like it is like stifling me and i have no idea about what is going on .

Comment: could you post the code?

Comment: yes i did post the code as i typed "and this is the code of the program :"

Comment: Hm, weird. didnt see that, expected it to be more code as the traceback points out your code executed on line 20. And what is weird is that is calling an index error when you're never calling for a list with a specific index

Comment: well about the lines , i am learning scapy , so i type a lot of code about scapy , but the only problem is when i use send or sr or etc these functions to send and receive data , then suddenly an Error occurs ..

Comment: This issue has been fixed on the latest dev version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it , but the only thing that did not work is sniff function , but that is fine with me .. Npcap did not work on my PC , don't know why , so i have installed WinPcap 4.1.3
and it worked correctly except sniffing packets in montior mode .
no need to uninstall Npcap .

Comment: This was fixed on the latest dev github version

Comment: i have the latest version of scapy so how this error happened ?